# Showing linear independence of infinite sets.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Show that the set ${\sin(nx):n∈N}$ is linear independent in $L^{2}[−\pi,\pi].$

In case of finite set I know, but if the set is infinite what shall I do?

thanks.

Comment: Can you show they are orthogonal? This will imply linear independence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Independence of an infinite set .](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312646/linear-independence-of-an-infinite-set)

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг why orthogonality will imply linear independence ?

Comment: @MathLover If $\sum c_n \sin(nx) = 0$, then take the inner product of this with $\sin mx$ for some fixed $m$, you will get $x_m \langle \sin mx, \sin mx \rangle = 0$. Since $\langle \sin mx, \sin mx \rangle  \neq 0$ ,this will give you $c_m=0$. Now, $m$ can vary over natural numbers, so this holds true for all $m$, giving linear independence.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг..... is the identity at the beginning of the second line in your previous comment right ? you said take the inner product of something that contains $\sin (nx)$, n not m,  with $sin mx$ and from where did $x_{m}$ comes? could u please clarify?

Comment: I am so sorry. That actually was $c_m$, not $x_m$.